# Executing same script on multiple browser with different login credentials using TestCafe

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, browser-automation

I want to execute my single test on multiple browsers in parallel but with sets of data.

I tried setting dynamic variable inside javascript code generated by TestCafe but while executing the code it is picking the same data for a particular run instead of using different data for different browsers.

Below is my sample code:

test('New Test', async t =>{

var email = "abc"+Math.random()+"@gmail.com";

await t 
.typeText(Selector('#email'),email)

Comment: I've checked this sample and it works fine on my side, I can see different values in different browsers. How does it correspond to your real test code? Is this variable declared in the test body in your actual project? Or, is it declared somewhere outside the test?

Comment: Yes it's working for me as well..as u mentioned I had declared it improperly.